# angular 5 get cookies with domain

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cookies, ionic3

(ionic 3)

I'm doing an authentication to a page to access some js files.

To access the files I need to log in, after logging in I can access these libraries that are loaded after a request are in:

```
192.168.0.102:8080/web/backend
```

with angular I make a request.

```
this.http.post ("/ auth", params, {headers: headers, withCredentials: true});
```

the request is successful, but the libraries are not accessible, I get an error "404 not found"

This is because when I make the ajax request I have a proxy with angular to be able to make the request

```
{
   "path": "/auth"
   "proxyUrl": "192.168.0.102:8080/web/authenticate"
}
```

The request returns a cookie and here is the problem, the cookie returns with a domain "localhost" and when trying to load the files I can not then perform the following tests.

1- Log in with firefox and then refresh the angular server to see if they load:
The page can load the files because I have a cookie with domain "192.168.0.102".

2- delete cookies and return to log in with angular, I install a firefox extension called cookieManager and edit the cookie so that the url is not localhost:
By changing the url of the cookie (Domain) I can load the js files.

Where is the problem?
That I have to change the domain of the cookie that I revived from the host and put the domain of the server in order to use that cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with Cookies never worked for me when I use `this.http.post(...)`. Instead use a `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
let data = {
        email: this.loginField,
        password: this.passwordField
      }

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST","http://localhost:8080/login", true);
  xhr.withCredentials = true;

  var change = () => {
    if(xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {

      //Return 401 Error code in your Backend (JSON Format)
      if (xhr.status != 401) {

        //User is allowed to log in
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
        localStorage.setItem("user", xhr.responseText);

      } else {
        //User isnt allowed to log in -> Error Handling
        console.log("Wrong Email or password");
        this.incorrectInupt();
      }
    }
  }

  xhr.onreadystatechange = change;

  xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://localhost:8100");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Now the cookie is installed in Ionic-Client.

**Note:** If your Ionic-Server also runs on localhost:8100 you can just copy-paste the request headers. Otherwise change the link in the requestheader to your Ionic-Server-Adress.